# Explicit Casting Problem

Tags: c#, generics, casting, explicit

```
// The Structure of the Container and the items
public interface IContainer <TItem> where TItem : IItem
{

}

public class AContainer : IContainer<ItemA>
{

}

public interface IItem
{

}

public class ItemA : IItem
{

}

// Client app

[Test]
public void Test ()
{
 IContainer<IItem> container = new AContainer();
}
```

Question : In test the following error occures. What can be the solution for casting?

Cannot implicitly convert type 'AContainer' to 'IContainer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: This issue seems to come up most days. Did you search before posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another generics covariant problem...

Generic types in .NET are not covariant or contravariant - IContainer<ItemA> (which is what AContainer is) is not a subclass of IContainer<IItem> - there is no valid cast between the two. This will be fixed in C# 4.

Comment: I note that in C# 4 we are adding covariance and contravariance **but** only on interfaces and delegates with reference type arguments in the varying positions, and only those interfaces and delegates which are known at compile time to be safe for variance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `AContainer` to be an `IContainer<IItem>`, you need to implement this interface as well:

```
public class AContainer : IContainer<ItemA>, IContainer<IItem>
```

You may implement it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [Simulated Covariance for .NET Generics by Krzysztof Cwalina](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2008/04/02/SimulatedCovariance.aspx)