# C# Cannot convert from `Inherited Class` to `Base Class`

Tags: c#, generics

I've got the following code:

**Simple Classes**

```
public class Transport { }
public class Car : Transport { }
public class Bus : Transport { }
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class Wrapper<T> where T : Transport
{
    public T Vehicle { get; set; }
    public void Brake() { }
    public void Accelerate() { }
}

public class BusWrapper : Wrapper<Bus>
{
    public void PickupPassenger() { }
}

public class CarWrapper : Wrapper<Car>
{
    public void GoRacing() { }
}
```

This is what I'm trying which gave me compilation error:

```
List<Wrapper<Transport>> list = new List<Wrapper<Transport>>();

list.Add(new CarWrapper());
list.Add(new BusWrapper());

list.ForEach(wrapper =>
{
    wrapper.Accelerate();
    if (wrapper is CarWrapper)
        ((CarWrapper)wrapper).GoRacing();
    else if (wrapper is BusWrapper)
        ((BusWrapper)wrapper).PickupPassenger();

    wrapper.Brake();
});
```

**Error**

```
cannot convert from 'CarWrapper' to 'Wrapper<Transport>'
cannot convert from 'BusWrapper' to 'Wrapper<Transport>'
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here, any workaround for what I'm trying to achieve here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to be covariant.

Comment: You're probably better off using an interface in a situation like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Convert Derived Class to Base Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955528/cannot-convert-derived-class-to-base-class)

Comment: When you are asking a question, you should first check the similar questions identified by StackOverflow.  In addition to the nearly identical question in the previous comment (which is even another problem in the transport domain), you might have found [Explicit Casting Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1443341/385844) and [Generics and casting - cannot cast inherited class to base class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3528821/385844).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the mistake of assuming that if `Car` inherits from `Transport` then `Wrapper<Car>` also inherits from `Wrapper<Transport>`. It does not.

You need to define `IWrapper<out T>` and use that for your list. Then this kind of covariance can work.

Comment: Except that his `IWrapper` interface is not actually covariant, so `IWrapper<out T>` will cause compile errors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction, i'm reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386(v=vs.100).aspx , almost got what I need

Comment: @BenVoigt - The `T` type only appears to be coming out. Can you explain further?

Comment: Looks to me like both in and out: `public T Vehicle { get; set; }`