# Why does the following doesn't compile? (involves generics and inheritance in c#)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This compiles:

```
    class ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class NewType: ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class Document
    {
    ReplicatedBaseType BaseObject;

    Document()
    {
     BaseObject = new NewType();
    }
}
```

But this does not:

```
    class DalBase<T> : where T: ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class DocumentTemplate
    {
    DalBase<ReplicatedBaseType> BaseCollection;
    DocumentTemplate ()
    {
    BaseCollection= new DalBase<NewType>(); // Error in this line. It seems this is not possible
    }
    }
```

What's the reason?

Comment: You don't have () after new DalBase<NewType> ?
//edit I've created a project, this is not the case

Comment: No, no.. that's because I just typed this from memory. Actual code is very long, so didn't duplicate here. Will correct it. Sorry. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit Casting Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443341/explicit-casting-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variance exists in C# 4.0 targetting .NET 4), but is limited to interfaces and usage of `in`/`out` (oh, and arrays of reference-types). For example, to make a covariant sequence:

```
class DalBase<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T: ReplicatedBaseType
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {throw new NotImplementedException();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class DocumentTemplate
{
    IEnumerable<ReplicatedBaseType> BaseCollection;
    DocumentTemplate()
    {
        BaseCollection = new DalBase<NewType>(); // Error in this line. It seems this is not possible
    }
}
```

But other than that... no. Stick to either non-generic lists (`IList`), or use the expected list type.

Answer (score 8):

As Andrey says, you want (generic) *covariance*. However:

- Generic variance is only supported in C# 4
- Generic variance isn't supported on classes
- In your real life case, this may be unsafe.

To go into the final point, suppose `DalBase<T>` has this method:

```
void AddEntity(T entity)
```

Now you've got something like this which you want to be able to compile - but would obviously be dangerous:

```
DalBase<Fruit> fruitDal = new DalBase<Banana>();
fruitDal.AddEntity(new Apple());
```

The second line would have to compile - so for this to fail at compile time, it *has* to be the first line which would fail.

I gave an hour long talk on generic variance recently which you may find useful if you want to know more - see the [NDC 2010 video page](https://web.archive.org/web/20101216073921/http://streaming.ndc2010.no:80/tcs/) and search for "variance". Alternatively you could read [Eric Lippert's blog posts on the topic](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) - but be aware that that will probably take longer than an hour ;)

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of Banana and Apple that way. :)

Comment: lol I think you've made more rep explaining covariance/contravariance than for any other subject on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because a `DalBase<NewType>` is not a `DalBase<ReplicatedBaseType>` - generics do not have co/contra-variance. In C# 4 you can get generic variance, but only on interfaces and delegates.

Answer (score 1):

the feature that you want is called "covariance" and was introduced only in C# 4.0 http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance

you code fails because there is no such cast (both explicit and implicit). Current rules of C# (<= 3.0) forbid it.

to check possible casts see §6.1.6 C# Specification

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ i didn't say that. i meant that in C# < 4.0 there is no way to do this casts (well, except for overriding cast operators)

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles in VS2010, net framework 4

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class NewType : ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class Document
    {
        ReplicatedBaseType BaseObject;

        Document()
        {
            BaseObject = new NewType();
        }
    }
    interface DalBase<out T>  where T: ReplicatedBaseType
    {
    }

    class DalBaseExample<T> : DalBase<T> where T: ReplicatedBaseType
    {

    }
    class DocumentTemplate
    {
        DalBase<ReplicatedBaseType> BaseType;
        DocumentTemplate ()
        {
            BaseType = new DalBaseExample<NewType>(); // no error here
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```