# Difference between as operator and casting (generics involved)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Recently I've run into strange issue related to casting. Every discussion/post I've seen tends to revolve around using casting when one is sure about the object being casted plus a couple of details. I haven't however found what's the reasoning behind the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var h = new SomeCommandHandler();
        var c = h as ICommandHandler<ICommand>; //this works as expected
        //var c = (ICommandHandler<ICommand>)h; //this throws - why?
    }

    interface ICommand { }
    class SomeCommand : ICommand { }

    interface ICommandHandler<I> where I : ICommand { }
    class SomeCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SomeCommand> { }
}
```

So why the second call throws an exception? What's the difference between casting and as operator that I'm not aware of?

EDIT:
It wpuld throw in the commented line above
"Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SomeCommandHandler' to type 'ICommandHandler`1[ConsoleApplication1.Program+ICommand]'"

Comment: @thecoop - hazarding a guess it's an InvalidCastException...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that's the whole entire difference right there.  The `as` operator returns `null` if the object can't be cast to that type, and just casting produces an exception.

Comment: Errr not sure how I overlooked that. I was pretty sure the "as" from example returned non-null value...

Answer (score 2):

Others have already explained the difference between the direct cast throwing an exception and `as` returning `null` when the cast fails. In order to be able to make such a cast *succeed* you will need to make the generic interface contravariant:

```
interface ICommandHandler<out I> where I : ICommand { }
```

However, this might not be possible, depending on how the interface really looks (I am assuming that you are showing a stripped down version for brevity). If your interface contains method that accepts an argument of the type `I` this will not work; the type `I` must appear only in get-operations:

```
interface ICommandHandler<out I> where I : ICommand 
{
    void SetCommand(I n); // this would not be allowed...
    I GetCommand();       // ...but this would.
}
```

Comment: Guess. I need it as a parameter (void Execute(SomeCommand cmd)) so, as you said, covariance won't help me. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It throws an exception because h is of type `SomeCommandHandler` which is `ICommandHandler<SomeCommand>` and you try to cast it to `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` whis is a different type.

Answer (score 0):

The cast fails because an `ICommandHandler<SomeCommand>` is not an `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117411/why-does-the-following-doesnt-compile-involves-generics-and-inheritance-in-c) for more details & examples.

The `as` simply returns null when the instance is not of the specified type, whereas the cast throws an `InvalidCastexception`

Answer (score 0):

the variable c is a is null. It doesn't throw because that's what using "as" means. In other words the instance h is Not an instance of ICommandHandler.

The next line throws because you're attempting to force a cast of an instance of SomCommandHandler to an instance of ICommandHandler

Make sense?