# How to write OfType<Foo<Bar>>()

Tags: c#

I have generic container class I'm using that I'm trying to write a OfType routine for. However the types I'm passing in are also generics. Here's an example:

```
Entities.OfType<Foo<Bar>>()
```

and my function definition:

```
public IEnumerable T OfType<T>()
{
    foreach (var e in Values)
        if (e is T)
            yield return (T)e;
}
```

If Entities are defined as a collection of `Foo<Base>` I get an error `Foo<Bar>` does not inherit from `Foo<Base>`. However Bar does inherit from Base.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Look up covariance and contravariance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit Casting Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443341/explicit-casting-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even though `Bar` inherits from `Base` -  `Foo<Bar>` and `Foo<Base>` are two completely different generic types not related through inheritance.

`Bar` and `Base` in this case are type parameters and C#4.0 supports covariance/contravariance for generic interfaces which may help you to solve the problem.

Your code will work in C#4.0 if `Foo` is an interface declared as following:

```
interface IFoo<in T> { /* methods, etc. */ }
```

*Note* that no method in `IFoo` may return `T`.

You'll be able to assign `IFoo<Base>` object to a variable of type `IFoo<Bar>` where `Bar` inherits from `Base`. This is an example of *contravariance*.

Answer (score 0):

C# Generics are not covariant. A `Foo<Bar>` is not assignment-compatible with `Foo<Base>`