# Does inheritance in generics work the same way as concrete and abstract classes, InvalidCaseException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate, generics

I have three classes: `Post`, `Post<T>` and `WallPost`.

Post is an abstract class representing a blog post with properties like `name` , `text`, `user`, etc.

The second abstract class is `Post<T>`, the generic version of post so I can implement a generic `GetChildren(T Post)` to get the children of a `post` and build a hierarchal list.

The third class is the concrete '`WallPost`' which is a specific post for a user's profile.

```
public class WallPost : Post<WallPost>
```

And finally a `Member` class which contains a collection of `WallPosts`.

---

I wrote a control that takes a collection of posts and displays it in a tree. One of the proerties I have on that control is

```
public IList<Post<Post>> Posts
        {
            get; set;
        }
```

(I use generics because I need to get the children, `GetChildren(T Post)`). and I set the type parameter as Post so it will accept any class that inherits from post, wallpost, blogpost, etc

Now my problem is that I want to pass a user's collection of `WallPosts` of type `IList<WallPost>` to the function and I get this error:

```
     Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.
PersistentGenericBag`1[BO.WallPost]'
 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BO.Post`1[BO.Post]]'.
```

I'm guessing this is because although you can write something like `Post p = new WallPost()` you can't have `List<Post> posts = new List<WallPost>()`

Anyways I'm completely baffled and I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you in advance

E

P.S. I use NHibernate and there is no mention whatsoever of a bag.

Comment: Man, the collection that you try to pass is obviously not a IList<WallPost>. Look at the exception, it is a NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit Casting Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443341/explicit-casting-problem)

Comment: I noticed that but nowhere in my code do I mention bags or anything, it's all IList

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use generic covariance in a way that is not type-safe.

What would happen if you write

```
List<WallPost> wallList = new List<WallPost>();
List<Post> pList = wallList;
pList.Add(new OtherPost());        //Not a WallPost!
```

You can only do with with read-only interfaces (`IEnumerable<Post>`), or arrays.

Comment: The problem is I can only use IList because of the Nhibernate framework.

Comment: ok I cast `WallPosts` to Enumerable 'AsEnumerable' and changed the datatype of the posts property in the control to IEnumerable<Post<Post>> and  get the error 'cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BO.WallPost>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BO.Post<BO.Post>>
'

Comment: @Eitan: A `WallPost` isn't a `Post<Post>`.

Comment: yeah but WallPost inherits Post<Post> this is getting to really be confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your NHibernate mappings.  NHibernate is treating your collection as a bag instead of as a list.

From the NHibernate perspective, a list may not be the appropriate choice.  A list gives you index-based access to the members of your collection, but you must have a list index column in your table in order for NHibernate to map it as a list.

You should probably check out the NHibernate collection mapping options and choose the one that best matches your case (set, bag, list, etc.).

Comment: I'm using the automapper so I'm not really touching the mapping files or anything

Comment: Well, you need to check your mapping setup.  Whatever is doing the mapping is mapping your collection as a bag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, you could use:

```
public IList<Post<WallPost>> Posts
{
    get; set;
}
```

and casting when assigning it:

```
bla.Posts = posts.Cast<Post<WallPost>>();
```